# Styling a table OR a list based form so that the labels and input fields width are set dynamically

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table

I need to create a form as shown in this image:

[image]

I am unsure if it is even possible to do with html.
The problem is that I can't get the labels width to change to exactly be as width as the content.

I tried it with tables and also with a ul list. 
Tables have the problem with the table size and lists the problem of the alignment.

I don't prefer one way or the other. I just want it to work.

Is there a way to do this?

edit:
Html:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr><td>NAAM</td><td class="rechts"><input type="text" name="naam" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>VOORNAAM</td><td class="rechts"><input type="text" name="voornaam" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>E-MAIL</td><td class="rechts"><input type="text" name="voornaam" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="vraag" value="vraag" /> VRAAG
                     <input type="radio" name="vraag" value="nieuwsbrief" /> NIEUWSBRIEF<td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td class="rechts"><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td class="rechts"><input type="submit" value="Verzenden" /></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

css:

```
#contactleft{ /* So: This is a div floating to the left with the adress etc */
 width: 250px;
 margin-top:50px;
 padding-top:10px;
 float:left;
 border-right: solid #b5b5b5 2px;
}
#contactleft p{
 margin-left:50px;
 font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
 font-size: 14pt;
 line-height:1.5em;
}
#contactright{ /* So: This is the div where the form is in. */
 float:right;
 width:690px;
 margin-top:50px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
 font-size: 14pt;
 line-height:1.5em;
 list-style-type:none;
}
#contactright form{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
#contactright form table{

}
#contactright form table td{

}
#contactright .rechts{
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 150px;
}
#contactright .rechts input{

  width: 100%;
}
```

Edit: I did it the ugly way. I just made a new table for every row and that delivered the result I needed.

Comment: Show us the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: @samirchauhan I am changing it constantly. Currently trying for a table style. I will paste the current code in the question

Answer (score 2):

Instead of table use this and style it accordingly :

```
      <div>
        <form name="test_form" method="post" action="">
            <label for="f_name">NAAM</label>
            <input type="text" name="f_name" size="35" /><br /><br />
            <label for="f_name">VOORNAM</label>
            <input type="text" name="f_name" size="29" /><br /><br />
            <label for="f_name">EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" name="f_name" size="35" /><br /><br />
            <label for="f_name">VRAAG OF NIEUWSBRIEF (KEUZEMENU)</label><br />
            <textarea cols="33" rows="4"></textarea><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="VERZENDEN" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: How can I change the width of the inputfield to "The rest of the width of the li"? When I set it to 100% it jumps to the next line

Comment: @Jarco : The width of the input field is set by the size attribute. Can you paste the latest working code in jsfiddle and send me the link of that fiddle so that I can have a look into it.

Comment: Can that size be dynamic? The input fields need to align to the right. http://jsfiddle.net/cgK37/